# Are there recommended practices for writing about oppressed peoples?

Tags: historiography, writing, ethnicity, decolonization, oppression

This question is about responsible historiography. History as written by winners tends to devalue and misrepresent the experiences of subordinate groups (see Textbooks: Zinn *People’s History*; Labour: Engels *German Peasants War,* Hammond & Hammond *Labourer* [Series], Thompson *Making* ; Gender: Engels *Family, Private Property,* James & Dalla Costa *Power of Women*; Race: CLR James *Black Jacobins*).

Many Anglo immigrants to California described its natives as lazy and dirty. If this was an attempt at ethnography it backfired, telling us more about the authors than their subjects. This example is extreme, but dominant discourses that reflect majority outlooks and deploy [otherness](https://othersociologist.com/otherness-resources/) are hard for authors from dominant groups to escape.

Those authors are prone to uphold [dominant narratives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominant_narrative) and "punch down" at other groups even by accident. The result is that writing about other groups can be considered dubious. An [article about fiction writing](https://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/are-white-authors-not-allowed-to-tell-stories-involving_us_59d11b90e4b0f58902e5cd35) asked "Are White Authors Not Allowed To Tell Stories Involving Black Characters?", while Richard Griswold de Castillo called inadequate Mexican-American history written by others *historia chicanesca* (Chicanoesque history). Minority groups have sought to tell their own stories instead of having stories imposed on them.

Despite these concerns, privileged historians do often write in good faith about disempowered minorities and the oppressed. Their work does ***not*** satisfy  subjects' understandable desire that their history be written by their own people. For this reason I suspect that historiographers have already spilled ink on the matter of writing about such groups without adding to the burden they already face.

Are there recommended practices in this area? I will speculate that [deconstruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deconstruction) of known narratives and meticulous [history from below](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/People%27s_history) could be elements of such a strategy. Hopefully something more systematized is out there.

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Edited in the hope of making clear that I am interested in identifying possible strategies rather than choosing one of them.

Comment: A Google search for the keywords _historians writing about oppressed_ found a number of sources that suggest there are no "_established best practices_", but there are a number of different suggested approaches, for example [Challenging History: Why the Oppressed Must Tell Their Own Story](https://www.globalresearch.ca/challenging-history-why-the-oppressed-must-tell-their-own-story/17824)

Comment: `privileged historians do often write in good faith about disempowered minorities and the oppressed` I would like to point that many of the oppressed people don't have access to academy and are unable to write their history in a academic way. As the academy lacks diversity, the alternative to having privileged historians writing is to not have historians writing.

Comment: @sempaiscuba My premise is that the stories will also be told by outsiders. The article you linked suggests as much by mentioning "historical perspectives which try to see the world from the viewpoint of the oppressed". ("viewpoint" strikes me as a bit sketchy.)

Comment: @AaronBrick That search gave quite a few results, the linked article was just one of them. However, nothing I found suggested anything like _established best practices_.

Comment: @sempaiscuba In light of your negative result, I have loosened the criteria.

Comment: Everyone brings bias to their studies. Regardless of how objective a historian tries to be, there is still going to be things affecting their viewpoint that they're not conscious of. The best you can really do is do your best within the framework of what you believe to be 'objectivity', and be aware that what you write will be read with the fact that you have biases in mind.

Comment: Unsure about your angle: California example is just chauvinistic. Writing of historians should be unbiased (but can't be); we should try that, but this project is not impossible and whites can write black history, an vice-versa. If this is about cultural-appropriation angle, or critical whiteness you should state that. If it's about avoiding bias, it's not only about "oppressed" or "vanquished".

Comment: @AaronBrick: you might be interested in a [recent episode of The Daily](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/02/26/podcasts/the-daily/oscars-green-book-interracial-friendship.html) on a very related topic (how to not do it/criticism of how it's done). It was fairly interesting (to me anyway) and the interviewee might lead you to a few interesting pointers (especially if you reach out).

Comment: @T.E.D. I thought h.kluber's deleted answer was a good one. This was the first suggestion of an actual best practice ("seeking a sensitivity reader from the community of the peoples you are seeking to write about").

Comment: Some people really hate this question! I am bemused.